# Connecting to an external cluster using VS Code Kubernetes Extension

Tags: kubernetes

I want to connect to a kubernetes cluster that's residing in Digital Ocean cloud using vs code kubernetes extension but I find no option to achieve the same. It's giving me an option to connect to either AKS or a local minikube cluster only. Any thoughts will be helpful pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Vs Code plugin mentions what to do when the cluster type is not supported: "If your type of cluster isn't listed here, don't worry. Just add it to your kubeconfig file normally (see your cloud or cluster documentation), and it will show up in Visual Studio Code automatically.". For Digital Ocean, I suggest you use [their documentation on setting up a kubeconfig](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/how-to/connect-to-cluster/). It should then show up as a cluster in the VS Code kubernetes plugin.